# R- find number of most efficient paths passing through a node

Tags: r, graph, nodes

I was wondering if there is a function in R that lets you find the number of most efficient paths passing through a node. Thanks you.

Comment: Do you use any graph package?  Your question is not clear. Try to edit your question and give more detail on your input and your expected output.

Comment: Do you mean the [betweenness centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Betweenness_centrality)? There is a `betweenness` function in the `igraph` package.